# How do I convert json to json-ld in.Net

Tags: c#, json-ld

I am trying to convert json to json-ld. So far I have tried the json-ld.net liberary from nuget (it is part of nuget3): https://www.nuget.org/packages/json-ld.net/

```
var jtoken = JsonLD.Util.JSONUtils.FromString(response);
var options = new JsonLdOptions();
options.SetBase("http://json-ld.org/test-suite/tests/");
options.SetProduceGeneralizedRdf(true);
var context = JsonLD.Util.JSONUtils.FromString(Properties.Resources.jasonldcontext);
options.SetExpandContext((JObject)context);
var jtokenout = JsonLdProcessor.Compact(jtoken, context, options);
var sz = JSONUtils.ToString(jtokenout);
```

the context resource:

```
{"@context": {
"ex": "http://example.org/",
"term1": {"@id": "ex:term1", "@type": "ex:datatype"},
"term2": {"@id": "ex:term2", "@type": "@id"}
}}
```

My json is present and valid. It comes from REST service. (response), and jtoken is populated. However, sz only contains the context:

```
context":{"ex":"http://example.org/","term1":
{"@id":"ex:term1","@type":"ex:datatype"},"term2":
{"@id":"ex:term2","@type":"@id"}}}
```

Comment: is your context resource correct? I tried it on this site, it couldn't parse it http://json-ld.org/playground/

Comment: I have simple json. I need to convert it to json-ld. If I put simple json into the playground, the result is nothing also. How do I do the conversion ?

Comment: I tried modified slightly your context with this context and it parsed ok, but I am not sure if it is what you want: {
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebSite",
   "ex": "http://example.org/",
   "term1": {
      "@id": "ex:term1",
      "@type": "ex:datatype"
  },
    "term2": {
      "@id": "ex:term2",
      "@type": "@id"
  }

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I framed the question incorrectly. POCO to JSON-LD can be accomplished easily with JsonLD.Entities on GitHub. If I start with POCO or convert JSON to POCO, then this works easily.

```
var person = new Person
{
Id = new Uri("http://t-code.pl/#tomasz"),
Name = "Tomasz",
LastName = "Pluskiewicz"
};
var @context = JObject.Parse("{ '@context': 'http://example.org/context/Person' }");
var contextProvider = new StaticContextProvider();
contextProvider.SetContext(typeof(Person), @context);

// when
IEntitySerializer serializer = new EntitySerializer(contextProvider);
dynamic json = serializer.Serialize(person);
```

Answer (score 5):

MXTires Microdata .NET is a good one. Converts .Net classes to Schema.org structured data in form of JSON-LD.

[Nuget Link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MXTires.Microdata/) | [Usage Link](https://github.com/idenys/MXTires.Microdata/blob/master/Tests/DemoTests.cs)